# Разные id в таблице mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Приветствую.

Имеется сайт, который выводит записи пользователей вида «id, name, goods, note, date, user».

Каждому пользователю показываются  свои записи (т.е. запрос такого вида “select * where user = пользователь")

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы у каждого пользователя id записей был свой, а не общий. Например 
1, предмет, null, 14.03.2018, admin ; 1, предмет, null, 14.03.2018, ne_admin ; 2, предмет2, null, 15.03.2018, admin; и т.д. Надеюсь понятно.

Как посоветуете сделать, каждому пользователю создать свою таблицу, чтобы id не путались или можно сделать все в одной таблице? Только как это сделать?

Comment: нормальная структура, имена пользователей только поменять на их id и всё. в чём путаница, в чём вы видите неудобство?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать и в одной таблице, для этого нужно будет убрать auto_increment с поля id а при добавлении записей в таблицу считать его отдельным запросом типа

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl WHERE user = пользователь
```

Ну и primary key сделать составным на поля id, user

Answer (score 0):

> Необходимо сделать так, чтобы у каждого пользователя id записей был свой, а не общий.

Задача легко решается, если будет сочтено возможным использовать в качестве движка таблицы MyISAM. См. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

> For MyISAM tables, you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix.

Т.е. в данном конкретном случае, например, так:

```
CREATE TABLE records (
    id     INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name   VARCHAR(xxx), 
    goods  VARCHAR(yyy), 
    note   VARCHAR(zzz), 
    date   TIMESTAMP, 
    userID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (userID, id),
    CONSTRAINT userID FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users (id)
) ENGINE MyISAM;
```